# StartActivity no inicia la Activity desde un servicio en Kotlin, Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, activity

estoy trabajando con Kotlin, tengo un servicio en primer plano que se encarga de iniciar una Actividad a peticion del servidor, el detalle es que en ocasiones funciona y en ocasiones no abre nada, estoy seguro que la petición si llega porque lo veo en el Logcat, pero tampoco me muestra error, solo no abre la Activity, investigando un poco parece que tiene que ver con la pila de actividades pero no logro entender que sucede, este es mi código para abrir la Activity, y como mencioné en ocasiones si abre y luego ya no.

```
   val intent = Intent(this@MiServicio,MiActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("extra","data")
        }
        intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        this@MiServicio.startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Elimina la llamada de  :

```
 intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

ya que hace uso de la bandera [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) , esta bandera debe ser usada con otras las cuales posiblemente no estas usando.

Comment: Si lo hago me manda este error:  Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag

Comment: Solo funciona cuando está abierta la Activity o cuando no está abierta?

Comment: Cuando está abierta la Activity si funciona, es decir si hago un start Activity de esa actividad se vuelve a abrir, pero cuando está cerrada, solo en ocasiones funciona pero la mayoría de las veces no hace nada, puse un println() para ver si pasaba por ahí y si, se ejecuta startactivity pero no abre nada